# I want to create beans in spring boot based on the servers like tomcat, jboss

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am aware of `@Conditional` annotation but not sure how to use it in this problem. Kindly tell me how `spring-boot` detects whether the deploying server is `tomcat` or `JBoss`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need some way of finding out in spring whether the application server your spring application is running in is Tomcat or JBoss or any other?

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code level , it more or less boils down to the following codes which try to use `ClassLoader` to load a class belonging to Tomcat/ Undertow (web sever used in WildFly (i.e. JBoss)). If the class can be loaded successfully , it concludes it is deployed to that server :

```java
classLoader.loadClass(className)
```

For example , to check if it is deployed to Tomcat , it can try to load `org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat`. For Undertow , it can check `io.undertow.Undertow`

When using with Spring boot , you could declare the beans using :

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(name={"org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat"})
public class Foo fooOnlyActivatedOnTomcat(){

}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(name={"io.undertow.Undertow"})
public class Foo fooOnlyActivatedOnUndertow(){

}
```

Comment: will the class loader loads the tomcat classes also?. one classloader will be available for one JVM am i correct?.